# Default tab not working with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, button, tabs

I'm somewhat new to web development and I was trying to create something similar to what was taught at: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

I made it but the problem I am having is the default open doesn't seem to work.  It has all three tabcontents opened instead of the default one.

I am not sure what am I doing wrong.  The buttons does work after clicking on it but when it loads up initially it seems to not work as intended.

Here is the code from jsbing: 
https://jsbin.com/qorofexofi/edit?html,css,js,output

```js
function startTab() {
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
}

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabfrontpagecontent, tablinks;

  tabfrontpagecontent =
    document.getElementsByClassName("tabfrontpagecontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabfrontpagecontent.length; i++) {
    tabfrontpagecontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tabfrontpage {
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  width: 40%;
  top: 3px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.tabfrontpage ul {
  display: inline-block;
  float: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabfrontpage ul li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.7s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tabfrontpage li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.tabfrontpage li.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabfrontpagecontent {
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  left: 15%;
  right: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabfrontpage">
  <ul>
    <li class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'test11')">Test1</li>
    <li class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'test22')" id="defaultOpen">Test2</li>
    <li class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'test33')">Test3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="test11" class="tabfrontpagecontent">
  </br>
  <h3>Test1Test</h3>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
</div>

<div id="test22" class="tabfrontpagecontent">

  </br>
  <h3>Test2Test</h3>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>

</div>

<div id="test33" class="tabfrontpagecontent">

  </br>
  <h3>Test3Test</h3>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
</div>
```

I appreciate any responses or help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

With jquery you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.toggle').on('click', function() {
    if($(this).next('.content').hasClass('active')){
      $(this).text('Show');
      $(this).next('.content').removeClass('active');
    }else{
      $('.toggle').text('Show');
      $(this).text('Hide');
      $('.content').removeClass('active');
      $(this).next('.content').addClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.content{
  display:none;
}

.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='#container'>
  <span class='item'>1</span>
  <button type="button" class="toggle">Show</button>
  <div class="content">Some 1</div>
  <hr>
  <span class='item'>2</span>
  <button type="button" class="toggle">Hide</button>
  <div class="content active">Some 2</div>
  <hr>
  <span class='item'>3</span>
  <button type="button" class="toggle">Show</button>
  <div class="content">Some 3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I got it fixed but next time I'll see how using this jquery method can work.

Answer (score 0):

you should put the id `defaultOpen` on the tab you want open by default
otherwise `document.getElementById` will not be able to find it

`<li id="defaultOpen" class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'test11')">Test1</li>`

and you should also call in your JavaScript the function you created `startTab()`

Other than that, your code is working, here is your example updated https://jsbin.com/sipikefove/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Initially I checked my code and yours and it was didn't really have many differences.  Only different was that yours had an startTab() which I added in.  However, it still didn't work on the site.  Then I saw someone put the java script at the end of the body.  It worked then.  I had my load script on top of header.

So, usually loading javascript should be at the end of the documents instead of the beginning?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the CSS `display` property to `none` on elements you don't want to see -

```js
function startTab() {
  document.getElementById("defaultOpen").click();
}

function openCity(evt, cityName) {
  var i, tabfrontpagecontent, tablinks;

  tabfrontpagecontent =
    document.getElementsByClassName("tabfrontpagecontent");
  for (i = 0; i < tabfrontpagecontent.length; i++) {
    tabfrontpagecontent[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  tablinks = document.getElementsByClassName("tablinks");
  for (i = 0; i < tablinks.length; i++) {
    tablinks[i].className = tablinks[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  document.getElementById(cityName).style.display = "block";
  evt.currentTarget.className += " active";
}
```

```css
.tabfrontpage {
  left: 30%;
  right: 30%;
  width: 40%;
  top: 3px;
  padding: 3px 5px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  border-top-left-radius: 20px;
  border-top-right-radius: 20px;
}

.tabfrontpage ul {
  display: inline-block;
  float: relative;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

.tabfrontpage ul li {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  right: 50%;
  background-color: inherit;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  transition: 0.7s;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.tabfrontpage li:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  transition: 0.7s;
}

.tabfrontpage li.active {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.tabfrontpagecontent {
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  left: 15%;
  right: 15%;
  width: 70%;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  border: 3px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div class="tabfrontpage">
  <ul>
    <li class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'test11')">Test1</li>
    <li class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'test22')">Test2</li>
    <li class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'test33')">Test3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="test11" class="tabfrontpagecontent" style="display:none">
  </br>
  <h3>Test1Test</h3>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test1Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
</div>

<div id="test22" class="tabfrontpagecontent">

  </br>
  <h3>Test2Test</h3>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test2Test test test test test test test test test.</p>

</div>

<div id="test33" class="tabfrontpagecontent" style="display:none">

  </br>
  <h3>Test3Test</h3>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
  <p>Test3Test test test test test test test test test.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the javascript itself should have the others hidden in the function.  I found out that the js should be loaded at the end of the document instead of the head of the documents and it fixed my problem.